# Issue trying to execute a program and then minimize all windows

Tags: python, batch-file, automation, scripting, pyautogui

I'm trying to execute a Windows Batch file and then minimize every single window that is open (to make my Windows 11 screen clean) using Python but Im not fulfilling the objective.
**My code is able to execute the Batch OR minimize all the windows but not both functions together** and I can't find a way to fix it.
Basically want to execute my batch and then minimize all the windows, in this way I can make the Python script execute at Windows 11 boot so it will open my batch and then minimize everything so the terminal window doesn't keep open and makes my screen clean as nothing happened :)

The problem here is that the batch is running successfully but windows are not getting minimized, this changes if I remove the **os.startfile** function and only keep the **pyautogui.hotkey** function, now the the windows are getting minimized but clarely the batch is not running.
**I can't keep both functions working together.**
Thanks for your time

```
import pyautogui
import time
import os

os.startfile('"C:/Users/villa/Desktop/ETH.lnk"') #Excecutes the batch.
time.sleep(5) #Waits 5 secs to make sure the batch is already running before minimizing everything.
pyautogui.hotkey('win','m') #This is the Windows hotkey that minimizes all windows.
```

Comment: Please read first the Microsoft documentation for the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) and the [STARTUPINFO](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfow) structure. Then you should have the knowledge how executables are started on Windows by any Windows executable capable starting another executable. Next right click on the file `ETH` on your Windows desktop and click on last context menu item __Properties__.

Comment: In the opened dialog window with multiple tabs there can be seen the properties of the shortcut file with __Target__ (= `lpCommandLine`), __Start in__ (= `lpCurrentDirectory`), etc. So most of the properties in a shortcut file (`.lnk` file) determine the data which are passed by `explorer.exe` processing a shortcut file to `CreateProcess` using the `STARTUPINFO` structure. Then read the Python documentation for the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) which is on Windows a Python wrapper module for `CreateProcess` and `STARTUPINFO`.

Comment: Next open a command prompt window and run `cmd /?` to get output the usage help of the Windows Command Processor `cmd.exe` which is always in the directory `%SystemRoot%\System32`. There can be used [os.environ](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ) to get the string value of environment variable `SystemRoot` (with using `"C:\\Windows"` as default if this environment variable is very unlikely not defined at all). Now you should have the knowledge how to replace `os.startfile` by `subprocess.Popen` with the correct function parameters to run `cmd.exe` to process the batch file.

Comment: But why is one of the most powerful script interpreters (Python) used to run a script file (batch file) processed by the oldest and at least powerful script interpreter (Windows Command Processor) which is still used nowadays? Whatever command lines the batch file contains, the same can be done with a Python script code too. There is (nearly) never the need running `cmd.exe` from within a Python script. It is always a poor design using two script interpreters if the entire task can be done with using just the more powerful script interpreter.

Comment: I recommend to read also the Microsoft documentation page about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file) explaining that the directory separator on Windows is ``\`` and not `/` as on Linux/Mac and how the Windows file I/O functions handle file/folder names or wildcard patters with a path containing `/` instead of ``\``. Last take a look on the Microsoft documentation page [Keyboard shortcuts in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-dcc61a57-8ff0-cffe-9796-cb9706c75eec).

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyautogui
import time
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen([r'cmd.exe', '/c start /b C:\Users\villa\Desktop\ETH.lnk'])
pyautogui.hotkey('win','m')
```